# Gae-init cannot sign in locally after setting email auth and feedback email

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running a local version of gae-init and logged in with my gmail as admin and then set app config such that email authentication is required for sign in /sign up and added my admin email as feedback email.

(https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init/issues/344)

Now locally, I can't sign in because it asks for email and password! I never set a password because I logged in with Gmail. When I deployed to appspot things work fine but now I cannot test locally. Can I reconfigure the app settings?

Also none of the front end loads locally while it does on appspot...help?

No option of Google sign-in:

[image: local sign in]

Answer (score 0):

Just disable your login protection in the code and you'll be able to login locally. Normally the local server should pick up the change automatically. Occasionally you may need to restart the local server.

Then adjust your auth code and re-enable the login check.

Adjusting the code could involve a dual login auth scheme - one for local one for production. Or the same scheme, if you can make it work in both environments. Can't get into more details as you didn't show your code.